# How to use two boolean parameter in ssrs tablix?

Tags: reporting-services

I have several records in database and those records have two field named finance stage(value =collected) and project stage(value=completed)

Most of the records have both field filled with collected and completed. Therefore i want to create two boolean parameters which shows/filter only the records having finance value is collected and have project stage is completed when both parameter is true.
i have used x++ and wants to filter tablix for that parameter on report.

Any other suggestion will be higly appreciated

Thank you for reading and regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSRS, you could use the visibility property of the row, and hide/show it according to the right field.
Example:
Visibility (hidden) property of the row

```
=IIf(Fields!Finance.Value)="Collected", FALSE,TRUE)
```